# How to adjust the width of a web page for different resolutions when resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The above code is working fine for 1280px values because i had used  accordingly. But i need that it should work for all resolutions. I need to know where the actual changes need to be done. Any suggestions?

```
      <!--  CSS for header: -->

        html,body{
            margin:0;
            padding:5;
            font-size:14px;
            font-family:"Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Verdana;
            background-color:#ffffff;       /* #F2FBFD;*/
            ovewrflow:hidden;
            height: 100%
        }

        .clear
        {
            clear:both;
        }
        #wrapper
        {   
            height:100%;
            width:1280px;/*controls width of division*/
           /*  overflow-x:hidden;
            overflow-y:hidden;  */
        }
        .header { 
        width:1280px;
        height:50px;
        margin:0px auto 10px;
        padding:1px;
        border-top-style:outset;
        border-top:3px;     /* #1c5a80; */
        font-size:30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }



      <!-- CSS for Menu: -->

        ul.Menu ul{display:none;}
        ul.Menu li:hover>ul{display:block;}
        ul.Menu ul{position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;}
        ul.Menu ul ul{position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;}
        ul.Menu,ul.Menu ul {
            margin:0px;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0px 2px 2px 0px;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            background-repeat:repeat;
            border:0px solid #AAAAAA;
            width:1280px;  /*Controls width of menu*/ 
        }
        ul.Menu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.Menu {
            display:block;
            zoom:1;
            float: left;
        }
        ul.Menu ul{
            width:180px;  /*Controlling width of submenu*/
        }
        ul.Menu li{
            display:block;
            margin:1px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        ul.Menu a:active, ul.Menu a:focus {
        outline-style:none;
        }
        ul.Menu a, ul.Menu li.dis a:hover, ul.Menu li.sep a:hover {
            display:block;
            vertical-align:middle;
            background-color:#8E8E8E;                            /*#1c5a80;*/
            border-width:0px;
            border-color:#1c5a80;
            border-style:solid;
            text-align:left;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:8px 27px;
            _padding-left:0;
            font:normal 12px Verdana;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;
            cursor:default;
        }
        ul.Menu span{
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        ul.Menu li {
            float:left;
        }
        ul.Menu ul li {
            margin-left:2px;
            /*width:200px; ----for controlling subMenu width*/
            float:none;
        }
        ul.Menu ul a {
            text-align:left;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        ul.Menu li.sep{
            text-align:center;
            padding:0px;
            line-height:0px;
            height:100%;
        }
        ul.Menu li.sep span{
            float:none; padding-right:0;
            width:5;
            height:16;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:#AAAAAA;   background-image:none;}
        ul.Menu ul li.sep span{
            width:80%;
            height:3;
        }
        ul.Menu li:hover{
            position:relative;
        }
        ul.Menu li:hover>a{
            background-color:#696969;
            border-color:#665500;
            border-style:solid;
            font:normal 12px Verdana;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.Menu li a:hover{
            position:relative;
            background-color:#696969;
            border-color:#665500;
            border-style:solid;
            font:normal 12px Verdana;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.Menu li.dis a {
            color: #AAAAAA !important;
        }
        ul.Menu img {border: none;float:left;_float:none;margin-right:4px;width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.Menu ul img {width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.Menu img.over{display:none}
        ul.Menu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
        ul.Menu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
        ul.Menu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none}
        ul.Menu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline}
        ul.Menu a:hover img.over,ul.Menu a:hover ul img.def,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over{display:inline}
        ul.Menu a:hover img.def,ul.Menu a:hover ul img.over,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def{display:none}
        ul.Menu a:hover ul,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover ul,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul{display:block}
        ul.Menu a:hover ul ul,ul.Menu a:hover a:hover ul ul{display:none}
        ul.Menu span{
            display:block;
            background-image:url(assets/images/arrv_anim_1.gif);
            background-position:right center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
           padding-right:11px;}
        ul.Menu li:hover>a>span{    background-image:url(./assets/images/arrv_anim_1o.gif);
        }
        ul.Menu a:hover span{   _background-image:url(assets/images/arrv_anim_1o.gif)}
        ul.Menu ul span,ul.Menu a:hover table span{background-image:url(assets/images/arr_double_1.gif)}
        ul.Menu ul li:hover > a span{   background-image:url(assets/images/arr_double_1o.gif);}
        ul.Menu table a:hover span,ul.Menu table a:hover a:hover span,ul.Menu table a:hover a:hover a:hover span{background-image:url(./images/arr_double_1o.gif)}
        ul.Menu table a:hover table span,ul.Menu table a:hover a:hover table span{background-image:url(assets/images/arr_double_1.gif)}
        ul.Menu ul ul.left{left:-180px;}


      <!-- The div section where i am including header.menu,body and footer pages: -->



        <div id="wrapper">

                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
                <div id="content" style="height:80%;">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
                </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: look up [media queries and responsive design](http://www.google.com/search?q=media+queries+and+responsive+design)

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning you should have started working with percentages (%) instead of px. But it might not be too late.

http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/advanced_web_design.asp

Read step 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Step 3: While converting your design to HTML make sure all your tables are measured in terms of percentages".  Stopped reading.  Closed page.  Cleared history.  Washed my eyes with soap.

Comment: i know its a long text. Just pasted. Also while converting from pixels to percentage should i start with wrapping menu section inside a table?

Comment: Start outside, set your body width to 100% (or less if you dont want to take the whole screen) and then work inwards and set all your objects respective widths how to would want them to display on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid system like http://960.gs/ or http://cssgrid.net/ that works also on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

percentages and media queries **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries** they act something like a conditional.